# PHP formularios arrays asociativos

Tags: php, array, formularios

He empezado hace poco a aprender por mi cuenta sobre PHP, estoy intentando hacer un formulario donde introducir un nombre y una cantidad e insertar el código de PHP en la siguiente estructura html, y se pide:

-Añadir los nuevos datos de nombre y cantidad a una lista que se tiene que imprimir en la misma página de html (yo he conseguido imprimir los datos que introduzco pero una vez introduzco otros se me resetea y no hace la lista que quiero)

-Si el nombre introducido ya existe en el listado y se introduce una nueva cantidad, se actualiza la cantidad anterior y se sustituye por la nueva.

-Si el nombre que se introduce ya existe en el listado y no se indica cantidad, se elimina la lista.

En el ejercicio obliga usar arrays asociativos y no deja el uso de sesiones.
A pesar de que probé con diferentes bucles como foreach tampoco logré resultado. ¿Quizás también tenga que usar input hidden?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Campaña de Crowdfunding </title>
    <link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    
    <h1>Campaña de Crowdfunding </h1>
    
    <h2>Realizado por: <strong>escribe aquí tu nombre</strong></h2>
    
    <p class="aviso">No hay donaciones</p>
    
    <table class="conborde">
        <tr><th>NOMBRE</th> <th>CANTIDAD</th></tr>
    </table>
    
    <p>Total recaudado: <span class="grande">0 €</span></p>
    
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p> <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label> <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required/> </p>
        <p> <label for="cantidad">Cantidad: </label> <input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad"/> </p>    
        
        <p><input type="submit" value="Donar" name="submit" /> 
        <input type="reset" value="Cancelar" /></p>
        
    
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
            $donaciones=[];
            $donaciones=unserialize($_POST["donaciones"]);
            
            $nom = $_POST["nombre"];
            $can = $_POST["cantidad"];
            
            $donaciones[]["nombre"] = $nom;
            $donaciones[]["cantidad"] = $can;
            
            foreach ($donaciones as $n=>$array){
                foreach ($array as $clave=>$valor){
                    echo "-".$valor;
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
        <input type="text" name="donaciones" value='<?php echo serialize($donaciones); ?>' />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para aclarar si _deja el uso de sesiones_ se refiere a que se pueden usar sesiones o no.

Comment: No deja el uso de sesiones, error mío al escribir la pregunta, ya lo edite.

Comment: Tienes que guardar la lista en algún lado, ya sea _cookies_, archivo de texto o algún otro medio que te permita leer y agregar, modificar o eliminar. La última opción sería incluir toda la lista en el formulario, probablemente un arreglo serializado en un campo oculto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casi lo tienes. Si no se puede usar ningún tipo de almacenamiento externo, ni sesiones, entonces los datos serán volátiles. Solo vivirán mientras le estés dando clic a los botones.

Como estás usando serialize, lo quise poner de esa manera, aunque también sirve usar JSON.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $nom = $_POST["nombre"];
        $can = ($_POST["cantidad"] != '') ? $_POST["cantidad"] : 0;
        $donaciones = unserialize($_POST["donaciones"]);
        if(array_key_exists($nom, $donaciones) and ($can == 0)) {
            // Si existe un nombre y la cantidad es vacia o 0
            unset($donaciones[$nom]); // Borra el elemento
        } elseif($can != 0) {
            // Si la cantidad no es 0, insertara o actualizara el registro si existe
            $donaciones[$nom] = $can;
        } else {
            // No existe ese nombre para eliminar (No hace nada)
        }
    } else {
        // Si se carga la pagina por primera vez, el array de donantes estará vacio.
        $donaciones = array();
    }
    ?>
    <p>Total recaudado: <span class="grande"><?php echo array_sum($donaciones);?> €</span></p>
    
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p> <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label> <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required/> </p>
        <p> <label for="cantidad">Cantidad: </label> <input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad"/> </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="donaciones" value='<?php echo serialize($donaciones); ?>' />
        <p><input type="submit" value="Donar" name="submit" /> 
        <input type="reset" value="Cancelar" /></p>
    </form>
    
    <?php
    // Listar todos los donantes
    foreach($donaciones as $clave=>$valor){
        echo $clave . ' - ' . $valor . '<br />'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    ?>
```